# Generic Functional Interface that accepts and returns same type

Tags: java, function, lambda, functional-interface

I'm looking for a functional interface that satisfies the following two requirements:

- Should accept and return the same type
- The type should be inferred while calling the method on the FunctionalInterface

If the requirement had just been the first, I can create a simple FunctionalInterface as follows:

```
@FunctionalInterface 
public interface MonoFunction<T> {
    T apply (T arg);
}
```

But, this would require the type to be specified while using the interface. But, I want the type to be inferred. Something like the below pseudo-code:

```
class A {
    int a;
}

class B {
    int b;
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    A a;
    B b;

    MonoFunction foo = (obj) -> {
        system.out.println (obj)
        return obj;
    };

    a = foo.apply (new A());
    b = foo.apply (new B());
}
```

How do I achieve something like this?

Comment: That's not how Java generics work. You must specify the generic parameters of the type in a _variable declaration_.

Comment: @Hashken Would you rather: (1) declare the type upon defining the function (e.g., `MonoFunction<A> foo = ...`) but not when applying it, or (2) lose type safety (e.g., `ClassCastException` can be thrown when using `MonoFunction` inappropriately)? I think I can get either to work.

Comment: You're looking for the `UnaryOperator<T>` extending `Function<T, T>` but I'm not sure why you want the type to be infered automatically. This will not work.

Comment: @pkpnd: How would go about implementing option 2 (Lose type safety)?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [**`UnaryOperator<T>`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html) but you have to define beforehand what type you're expecting.

```
UnaryOperator<A> foo = a -> {
    System.out.println(a);
    return a;
};
```

Otherwise, just cast your result into the variable type :

```
a = (A) foo.apply (new A());
b = (B) foo.apply (new B());
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a generic factory method returning the function:

```
static <T> UnaryOperator<T> getFooFunction() {
    return obj -> {
        System.out.println(obj);
        return obj;
    };
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    A a;
    B b;

    UnaryOperator<A> fooA = getFooFunction();
    a = fooA.apply(new A());
    UnaryOperator<B> fooB = getFooFunction();
    b = fooB.apply(new B());
    System.out.println(fooA==(Object)fooB);
}
```

Note that `getFooFunction()` does not only return the same function semantically, given the current implementation (HotSpot/OpenJDK), it will even be the same object, as you can test easily via `fooA==(Object)fooB`, so there is no reason to sacrifice the Generic’s type safety.

It’s the same thing that happens when you use `UnaryOperator.identity()`.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers already discuss how to use `UnaryOperator<T>`. While that approach provides the type safety of Java generics, you still have to specify the type upon creating the `UnaryOperator`. While I would recommend the `UnaryOperator` approach in most situations, you specifically asked (in the comments) how one might avoid specifying the type `<T>`, even if you had to give up type safety.

You can make a `MonoFunction` implementation as follows (unsafe and usually not recommended):

```
public class MonoFunction {
    private UnaryOperator<Object> func;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> MonoFunction(UnaryOperator<T> func) {
        this.func = (UnaryOperator<Object>) func;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T apply(T obj) {
        return (T) func.apply(obj);
    }
}
```

Note that this is *not* a `@FunctionalInterface`, so you'll have to put your lambda expression inside a `new MonoFunction(...)` call, as follows:

```
public class MonoFunctionTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a;
        B b;

        MonoFunction foo = new MonoFunction((obj) -> {
            System.out.println(obj);
            return obj;
        });

        a = foo.apply(new A()); // toString in A
        b = foo.apply(new B()); // toString in B

        MonoFunction bad = new MonoFunction((A obj) -> {
            System.out.println(obj);
            return obj;
        });

        a = bad.apply(a); // toString in A
        b = bad.apply(b); // ClassCastException: B cannot be cast to A
    }
}

class A {
    public String toString() { return "toString in A"; }
}
class B {
    public String toString() { return "toString in B"; }
}
```

I stress again that this is unsafe, and it is relatively easy to get a `ClassCastException` as demonstrated.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using a generic method within a functional interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Identity {
    < T > T apply( T input );
}
```

Unfortunately an interface defined like this cannot be implemented using a lambda function. Instead it must be done the old way using a class, and most concisely with an anonymous class:

```
Identity id = new Identity() {
    public < T > T apply( T anyInput ){
        // do something
        return anyInput;
    }
};
```

This then works for any input:

```
class A {
    int a = 1;
}

String outputString = id.apply( "one" );
int outputInteger = id.apply( 1 );
A outputClass = id.apply( new A() );
```